# Figure quality is deteriorated when included in EPS format

Tags: pdftex, eps

I am trying to add a contour plot to my document which is being compiled using TexStudio in ubuntu. I want to include the figure as EPS but when I do it, the output appears as a very unclear image. The size of the EPS file is around 103 MB.

How can I successfully generate the output PDF without the figure quality being deteriorated ?

Comment: pdftex can not include postscript so it will call epstopdf (ghostscript) to convert it to pdf, this should be identical quality but you can always (preferably) convert yourself and include a pdf image rather than eps

Comment: do you really need a 103mb image in a document? If it's being printed at a normal paper size that seems an awful lot of data

Comment: Are you sure that your EPS is not encapsulating a bitmap figure? 103 MB of vector data is really a lot...

Comment: Although it does not pertain to digital documents, but only to paper-print, this is worth knowing in this context: Many print services will not accept PDF with vector artwork (other than simple rectangles, etc.) regardless of how it was produced. There are too many ways to do it wrong, and it absorbs valuable printer time for inconsistent results.

Comment: What sotware generated the `eps` file? I ask because some programs (notably Mathematica) generate oversized `eps` files by shading regions using enormous numbers of tiny polygons, when a few larger ones would work much better. I wrote [a program](https://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/index.htm) to fix this, but haven't updated it for some time (it may not work with eps generated by recent versions of mathematica).

Comment: @IanThompson I used Python to generate it.

Comment: Can you make the file available for download from somewhere? I _might_ be able to help with this (I can't be sure as I've never seen an eps generated by Python).

Comment: The latex file or the python code ?

Comment: The `eps` file.

Comment: @rallg it should be noted though that may other print services will accept PDFs with vector artwork, usually with good results - especially print services that specialize in academic print jobs such as PhD theses or (printed) journals.

Comment: @Marijn yes, especially those that specialize. Not my genre.